# Footer of blog page expanding in width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The html content of a new blog post is impacting the layout of my blogs footer.

**My footer noramlly looks like this:**
[image]

**[On one blog post](https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-blog-post/) the footer turns into:**

[image]

Here the width has flooded much wider than before.

It seems to be due to the HTML content on the page.

Example pages:

[Normal layout](https://www.moneynest.co.uk/how-to-retire-early/)

[Bad layout](https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-blog-post/)

I've tried testing different parts of the code but can't come up with anything?

Can you help!?

Comment: "Can you help!?" Not without seeing the code

Comment: I don't know what code is causing the issue that's why I've linked. It's something to do with the HTML I've added in the blog post.

Comment: easy, the content you wish to make smaller is placed outside the `class=content` div.

Comment: Most likely the second post messes up the HTML structure of the page, by not properly closing an element or something like that. (Errors is something you got plenty of, https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.moneynest.co.uk%2Ftest-blog-post%2F)

Comment: @SamJefferies posted an answer hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please read the [mcve] guidance; and then [edit] your question to include the minimum code required to reproduce your problem (you don't have to understand *why* it's causing the problem, but as you strip out the unnecessary styles and HTML you may figure it out as you go. For us the less code we have to read, decipher and work with the easier it is for us to help you and others in future with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on the first line close the quotes :

`<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">`

I think there is **4** of them you need to add this quot to like above.

And i see to many `divs`, here is a snippet :

```html
Property VS Shares - the two most popular investment classes in the UK.

But which over the long-term produces the greatest returns?

Growing up in the UK you'll be intimately aware of property prices in your neighborhood, rental costs and interest rates you'll likely aspire to own your own home one day and potentially even purchase a property as an investment.

At the same time, you've likely viewed investing in stocks and shares (equities) as potentially risky or even as a form of gambling - something your pension is affected by through faceless corporations working on your behalf. In all likelihood, you have much less exposure to equities compared to property.

Property can also be leveraged to improve your return, rented out or developed.

So it seems property is a clear winner? Why then when talking to an Independent Financial Adviser (IFA) people paid to tell you what to invest in rarely mention property as an investment? 

Was property your key to instant riches? Or were the IFA's and equities investors right? 

<h2>Embarking on a financially odyssey</h2>

In order to seek the answers, I began on my own mini financial odyssey, starting with diving into books on value investing, financial freedom and trading, talking with successful investors and following they're advise opening accounts and buying shares. At the same time, I attended property seminars, went on a 12-month property investing mentorship and eventually raised finance, purchased, refurbed and let out two buy-2-lets. 

As the experience started to unfold I began building data on both options in order to review at a later date.

<h2>Equities (Stocks & Shares)</h2>
Starting with equities I discovered the most efficient way to invest was through cheap low-cost index funds aiming to track the prices of markets (for example the FTSE 100) rather than beat them. These could be purchased and held extremely cheaply (for example 0.85%) and over the long-term generally out-performed actively picking individual stocks yourself (or even paying someone to do it for you).

From my own research I discovered long-term equities generally produced returns of <a target="_blank" href="http://www.swanlowpark.co.uk/ftseannual.jsp">10.99%</a> per year (1986-2017 average FTSE All Share Total Return).

This could be stretched higher if you did find one of the few investment funds that had been proven to beat the market over the long-term.

Equities could also be held in an ISA meaning you can bank huge profits and pay zero tax on your gains, unlike property which gets's hit with at least 28% tax making a huge impact on your final profits.

What really shocked me was the difference over the long-run between those who knew what they were doing and those who followed the invest and pray strategy!

<i>'When a man with money meets a man with experience, the man with experience leaves with money and the man with money leaves with experience - Anonymous.'</i>

Interesting, maybe the Independent Financial Advisors (IFA's) were correct when they warned me off property investing?

<h2>Property investing</h2>
Moving onto property like equities I found the difference between a sophisticated investor and the 'invest and hope' investors huge. For example, a sophisticated investor would look for rental yields of 8-10%, develop the property to improve its value and often purchase at a price below the market - locking in a profit from day 1. Compare this to the invest and hope strategy of buying somewhere close, not looking at the area's potential and often paying more than necessary.

Taking just one variable - the location and we can see how this might ripple out over time to impact the investor.

<p>Take a look at the chart below for Reading and Durham property sold prices (Land Registry 1995-2017):</p>

<img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Reading-Vs-Durham-Property-Prices.png" alt="South VS North Property Prices" width="600" height="371" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-917" />

<table class="table-hover" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px;">
<tr><td>Town</td><td>1995 Price</td><td>2017 Price</td><td>Total growth</td><td>Compounded growth per year</td></tr>
<tr><td>Reading</td><td>£55,266</td><td>£311,755</td><td>464%</td><td>21%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Durham</td><td>£38,130</td><td>£103,124</td><td>170%</td><td>7.72%</td></tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
What really shocked me was the difference over the long-run between those who knew what they were doing and those who invested and hoped both in volatility and in the final sum they ended up with.Reading saw an almost 300% extra growth compared to Durham, making a massive difference to the families net worth. What's even more shocking for me is that Durham property prices are still 16% cheaper in late 2017 than they were a whopping ten years ago in 2007...the financial crisis lives on.

You can see now how a single variable such as choosing an area has a huge significance to your profits over the long term.

However, one benefit property has over equities is leverage.

For example, by using a mortgage the cost of purchasing a property is significantly less than it's valued e.g. a £100,000 property would cost you just £32,000 (assuming 25% mortgage, £5k refurb, and 2k legal costs) rather than the full £100,000. 

If your property then increased over two years to £120,000, upon selling the property you'd receive £45,000 (£120,000 - 75k mortgage), a whopping 40.6% return on cash invested (ROCE), all while receiving rental income.

However like the IFA's claimed the average property increase at <a target="_blank" href="https://www.nationwide.co.uk/about/house-price-index/download-data#xtab:uk-series">6.18% per year (1986-2017 average house price increase)</a> was significantly lower than equities 10.99%.

I also found the costs of property investing and time input needed significantly higher than equities.

<h2>Government clamp down</h2>
Shortly after I finished purchasing the second property George Osborne rolled out a budget raining the hammer down on property investors.

For some time they'd been presented negatively in the press and this was offered both an option to capture votes from the younger generation and increase tax revenues at the same time.

The budget increased the tax on selling a property to 8%, increased stamp duty for investors by 3% and banned investors from claiming many expenses (including interest payable on mortgages). This made headlines such as 'buy-2-let is dead' and 'house price crash due' and furthermore it made my comparison even more difficult...damn it, George! 


<h2>Comparing the data side-by-side</h2>
At this point I was no clearer on which produced the greater returns, so to get a clear picture I began directly investing myself this benefited me through providing a clear picture on all the costs and profits available.

I then set out to build the first financial model accurately comparing property investing over equity investing including all the attribute missed off by financial reporters and IFA's (benefits of leverage, extra time and costs spent on property, tax implications, recent government changes, impact of fees on index investing, inflation rates etc etc).

Once the model was built I created charts to easily showcase the data, below are the results of hours spent mining the data:

<h3>Average property investor VS equities investor</h3>
I began with the historical data a typical IFA would use taking national averages since 1986 to compute everything from equities performance to interest rates.

The resulting chart looks like:

[caption id="attachment_912" align="aligncenter" width="600"]<img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Property-vs-stocks-and-shares.png" alt="Property vs stocks and shares" width="600" height="371" class="size-full wp-image-912" /> Property vs stocks and shares[/caption]

<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Click to show data assumptions</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Yearly property increase - 6.18%</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Property rental yield - 4.5%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Initial discount on property - 0%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Mortgage deposit - 25%</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Mortgage interest rate - 7.33%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Equities holding fees - 0.85%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Yearly equities increase - 10.99%</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="panel-footer">Shocked by the assumptions? Mortgage interest rate of 7.33% & annual property increase of 6.18?
 These are long-term averages since 1986 and are what an IFA would typically use when creating a comparison against equities.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

We can see the data an IFA would use does show equities clearly outperform property for both basic & higher rate tax payers and investors who purchase property within a limited company.

However what they'd miss out here is that typical sophisticated property investor's would never invest at these rates.

Aiming instead for significantly higher rental yield's than the historical 4.5% (typically 8%) and ideally create an initial uplift in value through a refurb, furthermore if we look at the time it took mortgage rates to drop to the current rate of 0.5% and work backwords they'll likely pay a much lower mortgage interest rate over the next 30 years than the past 30 years.

So taking this into consideration I created another model.

<h3>Sophisticated property investor VS equities investor</h3>

<img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sophisticated-property-investor-vs-equities.png" alt="Sophisticated property investor vs equities" width="600" height="371" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-914" />

<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Click to show data assumptions</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Yearly property increase - 6.18%</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Property rental yield - 8%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Initial discount on property - 20%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Mortgage deposit - 25%</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Mortgage interest rate - 4.5%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Equities holding fees - 0.85%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Yearly equities increase - 10.99%</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

We can see here, the property has burst onto the scene for everyone apart from the higher rate taxpayers. Showcasing how the sophisticated property investors have a huge advantage over the invest and hope investors.

I should have stopped here but like an addict, I dived back into the spreadsheet creating a final model. So far I compared:

<ul>
<li>Average property investors VS good equity investors</li>
<li>Good property investors VS good equity investors</li>
</ul>

What I'd missed is that your average equity investor likely over pays for someone to manage his or her financial affairs increasing the fees they'd pay and having investments that lag behind the average. 

<h2>Sophisticated property investor VS average equity investor</h2>

<img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Likely-equities-returns-vs-sophisticated-property-returns.png" alt="Likely equities returns vs sophisticated property returns" width="600" height="371" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-915" />

<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">Click to show data assumptions</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Yearly property increase - 6.18%</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Property rental yield - 8%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Initial discount on property - 20%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Mortgage deposit - 25%</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Mortgage interest rate - 4.5%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Equities holding fees - 1.5%</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Yearly equities increase - 7.5%</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Finally I've increased the equity fees to 1.5% (still much lower than most pay) and reduced the average return accordingly to 7.5%. You can see this has had a massive impact on the performance now putting property ahead for everyone (even higher rate tax payers).

Even more interesting is the huge impact minor adjustments make over the long-run, in this final example the basic rate property investor would end up 30 years later with £529,712 compared to his equity investing friend left with just £186,748. 

So it's apparent that the winner is the educated investor whether they specialise in property or equities.

An educated index investor will out perform the average property investor over the long-run whilst the sophisticated property investor will outperform your average equity investor.

Damn it Sam! Just tell me what to do!

In order to compare for your own sake I recommended you take into consideration your existing wealth (for example you can begin investing in equities with £100), income level and stage in life and time commitment (property investing takes a lot longer).

Then play with the financial model, honestly entering figures on a deal-by-deal basis to calculate whether you're better off in equities or property:

**INSERT DATA**


Sources:

<a href="https://tradingeconomics.com/united-kingdom/housing-index">UK House price index</a>

<a href="http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ppd/" target="_blank">Property sold prices for Coventry & Durham - Land Registry</a>

<a target="_blank" href="https://www.nationwide.co.uk/about/house-price-index/download-data#xtab:uk-series">Average property sold prices of 6.18%</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.swanlowpark.co.uk/ftseannual.jsp">Average equity returns of 10.99%</a>

<a href="http://www.liveyield.co.uk/blog/buy-to-let-yields-over-time-series/" target="_blank">Average rental yields of 4.5%</a> 

<a href="http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/Repo.asp" target="_blank">Interest rate averages of 7.33%</a>

<a href="https://tradingeconomics.com/united-kingdom/inflation-cpi" target="_blank">UK inflation rate of 2.85%</a>

<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4">Assumptions within financial model</a>
   
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">20% for property repairs & management fees</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Re-tenancy and re-find every 3 years</li>
<li class="list-group-item">5% non-claimable expenses</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Insurance and driving expenses at £200 </li>
<li class="list-group-item">Remortgage fees at £2,000 every five years</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Estate agency fees of 2.5% plus £250 mortgage escape</li>
<li class="list-group-item">£1,000 buying solicitor fee</li>
<li class="list-group-item">£1,700 holding fees upon selling (council tax, mortgage bills etc)</li>
<li class="list-group-item">2.5% estate agency fee</li>
<li class="list-group-item">£1000 selling solicitor fee</li>
<li class="list-group-item">£150 personal time</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

First 9 years would have incurred a loss which could of been carried over to reduce tax (to around £1,600, to simplify I simply removed the next £1,600 tax due.
```

Comment: I don't understand why I'd need to do this? Normally I just add HTML into a post and it works fine this time it's changed the footer I didn't add the content div either time. So can't amend the layout for this single post. It must be something else?

Comment: wow , that is weird so you have done a previous post the same as this and it worked as attended to? was there any updates on your wordpress? did you maybe edit an `.php` file , maybe index.php or something like that?

Comment: It is strange indeed no plugin updates/php files or PHP includes etc. The only thing I thought it could be was the use of some bootstrap classes? But removing these didn't fix it either? Copying and pasting the content into another post creates the weird footer again!

Comment: and tell me does your 1st post work perfectly and everything after that breaks? It could be that the first page uses a different html file than all the rest since its the `home` page, im just thinking not 100% sure , so it could be that your first page uses `index.php` and the rest maybe like `page.php` and the 2 pages html structure are different.

Comment: Thanks no it's posts, I have previously done 4 or 5 without any issues. I tried creating a blank one and that also works, I then tried one full or lorum ipsum as I thought the content might be overflowing but again it worked fine. Seems something in the content. The only content I've changed I've copied and pasted to: https://jsfiddle.net/yex3nkqd/

Must be something in there!

Comment: hahahaha simple fix on the first line close the qoutes ...`<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">`

Comment: @SamJefferies made allot of edits but should be fixed now with snippet code.

Comment: copy and paste snippet into post as is and it should work @SamJefferies

Comment: Ha! It's always the simple ones that get's me! Thanks so much.P.S. Do you mind minimising the snippet to just the div class with the missing qoutes? As I will get hit with a SEO penalty by Google when I publish the post and it sees duplicate content?

Comment: it gets us all, no worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

On the good layout, your shares and author section are inside `.content -> .container -> .central-container -> .middle-content` whereas on the bad layout, they are outside, the `.content` class.  Check your html on that.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why? I've only amended the text above the shares and author section?

Answer (score -1):

Check the post you are adding as it has some extra closing div at the end of the post, because of that this problem occurs. Make sure it don't don't have any extra closing div. Try to add simple text only

Comment: i dont see this extra `div` ?? after which class do you see this?

Comment: Unless this is just guesswork, this answer is not helpful. If it is not guesswork please enclose the line number of the extra div to help.

Comment: Can you send me the post which you are adding actually browser automatically adjust the div structure, as you said you just added the post and you get this problem you didn't add that section in the post.
just try to add simple text and you will understand, it happens in wordpress.